# Lazarus: после использования SetLength возникает exception class 'External: SIGSEGV'

Tags: массивы, классы, исключения, lazarus

Версия Lazarus 1.6.4 из репозитория Ubuntu 17.04.

Полный текст сообщения исключения:

> Project project1 raised
>   exception class 'External: SIGSEGV'.
>
> At address 431B31

Объявлен класс `TSomeClass`, который содержит в себе динамический массив.
В процедуре объявлена переменная этого класса. В данной процедуре производится изменение размера массива в этой переменной с помощью `SetLength()`.

Теперь, чтобы вызвать исключение exception class 'External: SIGSEGV' достаточно раскомментировать любую из двух закомментированных строк из примера. Короче говоря, исключение вызывается практически любым посторонним действием в коде, когда присутствует вызов `SetLength()` для массива внутри класса.

Если бы я создал обычный массив вне класса,  то есть просто объявил его в процедуре как обычную переменную, то исключение не возникло бы.

Также исключение возникает, если приложение было запущено само по себе, не через IDE. При этом выдаётся такой текст:

> Access violation.
>
> Press OK to ignore and risk data corruption.
>   Press Cancel to kill the program.

Прилагаю пример простого кода.

```pascal
unit main;
{$mode objfpc}{$H+}
interface
uses
  Classes, SysUtils, FileUtil, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  end;

  TSomeClass = class
    arr: array of Integer;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  someClass: TSomeClass;
  //anyVar: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(someClass.arr, 1);
  //Caption := IntToStr(2);
end;

end.
```

В чём причина такой проблемы?

Comment: `someClass := TSomeClass.Create;` - без этого неинициализированная переменная `someClass` указывает куда угодно

Comment: а вызов `SetLength(someClass.arr, 1);` портит какое-то место в памяти

Comment: Мне конструктор был не нужен, и я даже не думал, что его обязательно нужно вызвать. Спасибо большое, это именно то решение!